# Image file upload using angular 7 with php codeigniter

Tags: php, angular, codeigniter

> php-codeigniter

```
public function upload(){
    $image = base64_decode($this->input->post("p_image"));
    $image_name = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));
    $filename = $image_name . '.' . 'png';
    //rename file name with random number
    $path = "./uploads/images/".$filename;
    //image uploading folder path
    file_put_contents($path , $image);
    // image is bind and upload to respective folder

    $data_insert = array('p_image'=>$filename);
    if(!empty($data_insert )){
    $success=$this->db->insert('projects', $data_insert);

    }else{ } 
    if($success){
        $b = "User Registered Successfully..";
    }
    else
    {
        $b = "Some Error Occured. Please Try Again..";
    }
    echo json_encode($b);

}
```

In the above code i can't understand why the path is inserting 2 times in the database with 2 different paths and either 2 paths are not showing any image, iam not getting what's wrong with the code, iam new to this ,plz help me to sort out this...

> Angular

*component.html*

```
<div class="admin-page">
  <div class="add-projects-form">
    <form [formGroup]="myForm"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <!-- image upload start -->
        <div class="form-group">
        <div class="upload-image">
        <div #image class="image-wrapper"></div>
        <div class="browse-btn">
        <input type="file" name="cameraImg" id="cameraImg" (change)="onSelectedFile($event)" >
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div style="text-align: center;margin-top:40px;">
        <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" (click)="addProject()">Add Project</button>
      </div> 
  </form>
</div>
</div>
```

*component.ts*

```
onSelectedFile(event) {
  if (event.target.files.length > 0) {
  const productImage = event.target.files[0];
  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('p_image', productImage);
  console.log(productImage.name);
  console.log(productImage);
  this.adminService.uploadImage(productImage).subscribe(
  res => {
  if (res){
  console.log('success')
  this.uploadError = '';
  } else {
  // this.uploadError = res.response.message;
  }
  },
  err => this.error = err
  );
  }
  }
```

*service.ts*

```
  uploadImage(p_image){
    return this.http.post(`${CONFIG.API_URL}/Welcome/upload`, p_image);
  }
```

This is my angular code for the image file upload,i have no issue with this code it is getting correct output on console but the only thing is issue with the backend codeigniter code.

Comment: Please provide your angular code

Answer (score 0):

1. Every time that you insert a image in the input it will upload to the backend(maybe you want to move that after click a button)
2. You only want to upload 1 image or multiple?
3. You are decoding the image in your php you should omit that because you are uploading a binary with formData not a string(im not expert with php maybe im wrong but in node just save the binary in a folder).